# Do PMs get paid less for in-house apps compared to public-facing ones?

Tags: product-management, career

I've been tasked with managing an in-house analytics app that was developed by a past colleague. It's only used for internal client accounts (we're an agency) but we're considering bringing it to market down the road.

Question— do PMs working solely on in-house apps get paid less than ones working on public-facing ones? Seems to me there's less return on investment to quantify and measure success against for internal apps (save for improvements in efficiency) since there are no direct purchase revenues coming in.

So is it considered less valuable in the PM world?

Comment: I’d like to understand if there are reasons why you would believe this to be true. Normally, we prefer questions that relate to an actual problem you are currently facing.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously it is possible that a PM for a particularly prestigious product would command a higher salary. However, past that, salary differences are often more about where you work and your experience than the type of project. It's useful to remember that there are some companies that are only able to offer the services they do because of very strong internal tooling. Tooling projects can be as strong of a market differentiator and driver of value as sold projects can.

Answer (score 1):

Wage rate is determined by supply and demand of labor.  You may be seeing a correlation between in-house apps or apps designed to be sold but I doubt this is a causal variable to any real degree.  This is a great read on [Labor Market Equilibrium and Wage Determinants](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-economics/chapter/labor-market-equilibrium-and-wage-determinants/)